# Problems with creating HMAC signature

Tags: c, azure, openssl, hmac

I need to work with my Azure Blob storage in my programs written on C. I didn't found any C library to work with it, so I decide to write my own code using Azure Blob Storage REST API, curl and openssl libraries.

I found some [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103258/accessing-azure-blob-storage-using-bash-curl) script for making simple request to Azure storage what work well and start rewriting it into C.

For now I have some problems with creating HMAC signature for request. I'm newbie in cryptography and after some searching I found [this](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying).

Well, here is my code what will make simple GET request for list of blobs in storage:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "crypto.h"


#define VERB_GET                               "GET"
#define VERB_POST                              "POST"
#define VERB_PUT                               "PUT"

#define AZURE_API_VERSION                      "2011-08-18"
#define AZURE_KEY_TYPE                         "SharedKey"

#define REQUEST_HEADER_X_MS_VERSION            "x-ms-version: "AZURE_API_VERSION
#define REQUEST_HEADER_X_MS_DATE_F             "x-ms-date: %s"
#define REQUEST_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_F         "Authorization: "AZURE_KEY_TYPE \
                                               " %s:%s"


static const char *account_name = "<account_name>";
static const char *container_name = "<container_name>";
static const char *account_key = "<account_key>";



// at least 30 symbols for result must be allocated
static void get_time_now_gmt(char *result) {
    #define GMT_TIME_FORMAT_STRING "%s, %02d %s %d %02d:%02d:%02d GMT"

    static const char *nameOfDay[] = {
        "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
    };

    static const char *nameOfMonth[] = {
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *gmtime(&t);

    // return something like Thu, 07 Jul 2016 11:07:53 GMT
    sprintf(result, GMT_TIME_FORMAT_STRING,
            nameOfDay[tm.tm_wday],          // Day of week name
            tm.tm_mday,                     // Day
            nameOfMonth[tm.tm_mon],         // Month name
            tm.tm_year + 1900,              // Year
            tm.tm_hour,                     // Hour
            tm.tm_min,                      // Minute
            tm.tm_sec);                     // Second
}


struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};

static size_t curl_callback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, 
        void* userp) {
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *) userp;

    mem->memory = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if (!mem->memory) {
        /* out of memory! */
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}

void make_curl_req(const char *h1, const char *h2, const char *h3) {
    CURL *curl_handle;
    CURLcode res;
    char url[256];
    struct MemoryStruct chunk;
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;

    chunk.memory = malloc(1); /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
    chunk.size = 0; /* no data at this point */

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* init the curl session */
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    sprintf(url, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s?restype=container&comp=list",
        account_name, container_name);

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept:");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, h1);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, h2);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, h3);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    /* specify URL to get */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    /* send all data to this function  */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_callback);

    /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *) &chunk);

    /* get it! */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

    /* check for errors */
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
    } else {
        /*
         * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
         * bytes big and contains the remote file.
         *
         * Do something nice with it!
         */

        printf("%s\n", chunk.memory);

    }

    /* cleanup curl stuff */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

    free(chunk.memory);

    /* we're done with libcurl, so clean it up */
    curl_global_cleanup();
}

void print_it(const char* label, const unsigned char* buff, size_t len)
{
    if(!buff || !len)
        return;

    if(label)
        printf("%s: ", label);

    for(size_t i=0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%02X", buff[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char request_date[31];
    char x_ms_date[45];
    char canonicalized_headers[45 + sizeof(REQUEST_HEADER_X_MS_VERSION)];
    char canonicalized_resources[strlen(account_name) + 
                                strlen(container_name) + 5];
    char string_to_sign[1024];

    unsigned char *decoded_hex_key;
    size_t decoded_hex_key_len;

    unsigned char *signature = NULL;
    size_t signature_len;

    unsigned char *signature_based;

    unsigned char auth_header[256];


    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    get_time_now_gmt(request_date);
    sprintf(x_ms_date, REQUEST_HEADER_X_MS_DATE_F, request_date);
    sprintf(canonicalized_headers, "%s\\n%s", 
            x_ms_date, REQUEST_HEADER_X_MS_VERSION);
    sprintf(canonicalized_resources, "/%s/%s", account_name, container_name);
    sprintf(string_to_sign, "%s\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n%s\n%s\ncomp:list\nrestype:container",
            VERB_GET, canonicalized_headers, canonicalized_resources);

    printf("String to sign: %s\n", string_to_sign);

    base64_decode(account_key, &decoded_hex_key, &decoded_hex_key_len);

    print_it("Decoded hex key: ", decoded_hex_key, decoded_hex_key_len);

    hmac_sha256(decoded_hex_key, decoded_hex_key_len, &signature,
            &signature_len, decoded_hex_key, decoded_hex_key_len);

    free(decoded_hex_key);

    base64_encode(signature, signature_len, &signature_based);
    free(signature);

    sprintf(auth_header, REQUEST_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_F, 
            account_name, signature_based);

    printf("Signature: %s\n", signature_based);

    free(signature_based);

//    make_curl_req(x_ms_date, REQUEST_HEADER_X_MS_VERSION, auth_header);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Well, the result of request is incorrect digest. I try to print digest what generates bash script and code what I found and they are different.

Could anyone please help me how to solve this problem, because I have no ideas.

P.S. Created HMAC digests are different even if I put constant date into `request_date` in my code and `request_date` in bash script.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:

Ok, well, I recive next from azure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:71251945-0001-0020-1167-f16d5e000000
Time:2016-08-08T11:25:38.6226737Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'i4/LU2Rk8sBJ02kfokzzKz95QRUrOEDV8vwxNEo0uUA=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET











x-ms-date:Mon, 08 Aug 2016 11:25:39 GMT
x-ms-version:2011-08-18
/<account_name>/<container_name>
comp:list
restype:container'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

The signature what generates my code is `i4/LU2Rk8sBJ02kfokzzKz95QRUrOEDV8vwxNEo0uUA=` and bash script is `FZ/Kd4oQH7/aGqbgYBs0hsGIjm7JDcWQaGxkFlBKyrI=` for same values of `request_date`.

The value of string_to_sign is next:

```
00000000  47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a  0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 78  |GET............x|
00000010  2d 6d 73 2d 64 61 74 65  3a 4d 6f 6e 2c 20 30 38  |-ms-date:Mon, 08|
00000020  20 41 75 67 20 32 30 31  36 20 31 30 3a 34 31 3a  | Aug 2016 10:41:|
00000030  32 32 20 47 4d 54 0a 78  2d 6d 73 2d 76 65 72 73  |22 GMT.x-ms-vers|
00000040  69 6f 6e 3a 32 30 31 31  2d 30 38 2d 31 38 0a 2f  |ion:2011-08-18./|
00000050  3c 73 74 6f 72 61 67 65  5f 61 63 63 6f 75 6e 74  |<storage_account|
00000060  3e 2f 3c 63 6f 6e 74 61  69 6e 65 72 5f 6e 61 6d  |>/<container_nam|
00000070  65 3e 0a 63 6f 6d 70 3a  6c 69 73 74 0a 72 65 73  |e>.comp:list.res|
00000080  74 79 70 65 3a 63 6f 6e  74 61 69 6e 65 72        |type:container|
0000008e
```

I think, the problem is in passing `decoded_hex_key` passing into `hmac_sha256`. Maybe I have to transorm it before passing?

Comment: Can you please update your question and include the following: 1) What's the exact error you're getting 2) An output of your `string_to_sign` variable?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I've updated my question

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. I can see that the date/time returned by the server is `Mon, 08 Aug 2016 11:25:39 GMT` where as date/time you're providing is `Mon, 08 Aug 2016 10:41:22 GMT`. Please note that this discrepancy will cause your requests to fail. Do check the time on your computer and make sure it is not off by more than 10-15 minutes.

Comment: It's just examples. As I mentioned, I've put same date and time into `request_date` variables in bash script and into my code, and the result of signatures was different.

Comment: Oh! I'm not familiar with C++ so I don't know how base64_decode/base64 _encode works but when calculating signature, the key must be decoded using base64 decoding but the authorization header bytes must be converted to a base64 string using UTF8 encoding. Not sure how you would do that in C++ but that could be the reason why your signatures are different. HTH.

Comment: It's true when we use UTF-8 encoding for our strings. Default encoding of C-strings is ANSI, and the values of `decoded_hex_key` from the script and from my code are same too! Also, the result of all steps unless getting the signature are identical in my code and in script...

Answer (score 1):

I've resolve my problem. Looks like I use incorrect signature creation method, or used it incorrect (that is more probable).

So, I found next method, what I belive will be helpfull for someone.

```
static int hmac_sha25_digest(const u_char *msg, size_t mlen, const u_char *key, 
        size_t key_len, u_char **res, unsigned int *rlen) {

    *res = malloc((SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH + 1) * sizeof(u_char));
    memset(*res, 0, (SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH + 1) * sizeof(u_char));


    HMAC_CTX ctx;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);

    HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key, key_len, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&ctx, msg, mlen);
    HMAC_Final(&ctx, *res, rlen);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Easy peasy and serve all my needs.