# Using marker with Azure Storage List Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Based on the documentation for List Blobs for Azure Storage as mentioned here :- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135734.aspx

I'm trying to list the blobs in a container using the shell script mentioned in [Accessing Azure blob storage using bash, curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103258/accessing-azure-blob-storage-using-bash-curl)

The shell script works fine as it generates the correct signature.

However if there are too many blobs to list the response contains the NextMarker element.

The REST API documentation mentions that the marker value can be used in a subsequent call to request the next set of list items.

Does this marker needs to be included in the string_to_sign or would it work fine by just including it in the URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this marker needs to be included in the string_to_sign or would
> it work fine by just including it in the URL ?

Yes, this marker needs to be included in the `string_to_sign`.

From [`Authentication for the Azure Storage Services`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx) (Section: `Constructing the Canonicalized Resource String`):

> Retrieve all query parameters on the resource URI, including the comp
> parameter if it exists.
>
> Convert all parameter names to lowercase. Sort
> the query parameters lexicographically by parameter name, in ascending
> order.
>
> URL-decode each query parameter name and value. Append each
> query parameter name and value to the string in the following format,
> making sure to include the colon (:) between the name and the value:

Since this next_marker parameter is passed as a query string parameter, it must be included in signature calculation as well.

Comment: Do I need to specify marker:<marker string> or next _marker:<marker string> in the canonicalized resource string ?

Comment: Since the query string parameter is "marker", you would need to use that and not "next-marker". HTH.