# Storage service API call

Tags: bash, azure, curl, azure-storage-files

I try to create a file share on an existing Azure storage account via bash script. I only have the account name and key, but don't want to use login credentials. 
This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE_ISO=$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
VERSION="2015-02-21"  

curl --header "x-ms-version: ${VERSION}" --header "x-ms-date: ${DATE_ISO}" --header "Authorization: SharedKey mystorageaccount:?????" https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare?restype=share
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/create-share) says, "Authorization" is required (syntax: `Authorization="[SharedKey|SharedKeyLite] <AccountName>:<Signature>"`) and ["Signature" is a Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) constructed from the request and computed by using the SHA256 algorithm, and then encoded by using Base64 encoding.](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services)
So how do I generate this Signature?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but you would need to write some code to generate the signature. The process is outlined in the 2nd link you shared.

Comment: My question is: How does this code looks like? Can someone give an example?

Comment: Please see the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829911/azure-rest-api-put-blob. Take a look at `AuthorizationHeader` function there. You will need to write something like that only. HTH.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103258/accessing-azure-blob-storage-using-bash-curl) what goes into the right direction. But my question is about `file` and `create` instead of `blob` and `list`. I do not find any documentation on how the syntax has to look like. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to create *Share* with `bash` script.

```
#!/bin/sh

STORAGE_KEY="$1"
STORAGE_ACCOUNT="$2"
SHARE_NAME="$3"

DATE_ISO=$(TZ=GMT date "+%a, %d %h %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
VERSION="2015-12-11"
HEADER_RESOURCE="x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO\nx-ms-version:$VERSION"
URL_RESOURCE="/$STORAGE_ACCOUNT/$SHARE_NAME\nrestype:share"
STRING_TO_SIGN="PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$HEADER_RESOURCE\n$URL_RESOURCE"

DECODED_KEY="$(echo -n $STORAGE_KEY | base64 -d -w0 | xxd -p -c256)"
SIGN=$(printf "$STRING_TO_SIGN" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:$DECODED_KEY" -binary |  base64 -w0)

curl -X PUT \
  -H "x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO" \
  -H "x-ms-version:$VERSION" \
  -H "Authorization: SharedKey $STORAGE_ACCOUNT:$SIGN" \
  -H "Content-Length:0" \
  "https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT.file.core.windows.net/$SHARE_NAME?restype=share"
```

Try this to create *Directory* under the specified share.

```
#!/bin/sh

STORAGE_KEY="$1"
STORAGE_ACCOUNT="$2"
SHARE_NAME="$3"
DIRECTORY_NAME="$4"

DATE_ISO=$(TZ=GMT date "+%a, %d %h %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
VERSION="2015-12-11"
HEADER_RESOURCE="x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO\nx-ms-version:$VERSION"
URL_RESOURCE="/$STORAGE_ACCOUNT/$SHARE_NAME/$DIRECTORY_NAME\nrestype:directory"
STRING_TO_SIGN="PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$HEADER_RESOURCE\n$URL_RESOURCE"

DECODED_KEY="$(echo -n $STORAGE_KEY | base64 -d -w0 | xxd -p -c256)"
SIGN=$(printf "$STRING_TO_SIGN" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:$DECODED_KEY" -binary |  base64 -w0)

curl -X PUT \
  -H "x-ms-date:$DATE_ISO" \
  -H "x-ms-version:$VERSION" \
  -H "Authorization: SharedKey $STORAGE_ACCOUNT:$SIGN" \
  -H "Content-Length:0" \
  "https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT.file.core.windows.net/$SHARE_NAME/$DIRECTORY_NAME?restype=directory"
```

Comment: Awesome! I see it's also no problem to create a directory inside this share: `SHARENAME` must be sth. like `<share>/<directory>` and `restype` in line 10 and 21 must be set to `directory`